# Japanese fonts available in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, fonts, xamarin.forms

I'm building an app using Xamarin.forms.
And I need some Japanese fonts work on my app.
Do you have any lists of Japanese fonts available on Xamarin?
Please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't specify a font, the default/system font on each platform already supports Japanese characters. I'd recommend just using the defaults to start with.

There is a [localization guide for Xamarin.Forms](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/localization/) which might be useful for you... the sample includes Japanese localizations so you can see how the text looks

**screenshots**:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjC5J.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx3Kd.png

For iOS, you could also [set the font](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/fonts/#iOS) to one of [these](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIFont) - from [this list](http://iosfonts.com/). For Android and Windows it's tricker, I'd really stick with the platform defaults for those -- attempting to ship and reference custom fonts requires a bit of coding.

Incidentally, Xamarin.Forms is a framework that sits atop the native UI SDKs, so there aren't really "fonts for Xamarin". You need to work with the Font APIs on each platform (including which fonts are available by default, and how you embed custom ones in an app).